# assign number of matched elements in cypress to variable

Tags: typescript, cypress

as described with comment, need to change value of var inside cypress function
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because of asynchronous nature of Cypress, the last statement should be written as follows:

```js
cy.then(() => {
 cy.contains(`${total}`);
})
```